# New to python/tkinter and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, polygon, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to draw shapes from information given in a text file, the specification for the `DrawOnCanvas` function is as follows:

Write and test a function whose first line is

```
def drawOnCanvas(can, shape):
```

And which adds a shape represented by the dictionary shape to the tkinter Canvas can. The following fragment of code illustrates the operation of the function:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root,width = 200, height = 100)
can.pack()
shape1 = {'bounds': [20, 20, 80, 50], 'kind': 'rect', 'fill': True}
shape2 = {'bounds': [80, 50, 20, 35], 'kind': 'tri', 'fill': False}
drawOnCanvas(can, shape1)
drawOnCanvas(can, shape2)
root.mainloop()
```

My code currently looks like this but it only displays the rectangles, not triangles, I can't figure out how I'm supposed to do the triangles?

```
import tkinter as tk

def readShapes(filename):
    with open(filename) as openedFile:
        textSplit = []
        for line in openedFile:
            # str.rstrip() removes trailing "\n"
            splitList = line.rstrip().split()
            textSplit.append({
                "kind": splitList[0],
                "bounds": splitList[1:5],
                "fill": splitList[5]
            })
    
    return textSplit

shapeCoords = readShapes("foot_horiz.txt")
print(*shapeCoords, sep="\n")

def drawOnCanvas(can, shape):
    if shape["kind"] == "rect":
        can.create_rectangle(shape['bounds'], fill = 'black')
    if shape["kind"] == "tri":
        can.create_polygon(shape['bounds'], fill = 'black')

root = tk.Tk()
can = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white', height=500, width=500)
can.pack()

for shape in shapeCoords:
  drawOnCanvas(can, shape)

root.mainloop()
```

Foot horizon contains the information:

```
rect 20 20 80 50 True
tri 80 50 20 35 False
rect 80 20 115 62 True
tri 122 27 143 20 True
tri 122 27 143 34 True
tri 122 41 143 34 True
tri 122 41 143 48 True
tri 122 55 143 48 True
tri 122 55 143 62 True
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A polygon item requires at least three sets of coordinates. You're only providing two. You cannot draw a triangle with only two points.

Comment: How would I go about providing three sets if I'm taking information from the given file as bounds? sorry if this is stupid

Comment: @Isuckatcoding111: For one, you have to add an additional set of coordinates in the data. Next, you'll have to modify your code to be able to pull out three sets of coordinates if the `kind` is "tri". And finally, you'll have to use those coordinates when calling `create_polygon`.

Comment: "If a dictionary represents a triangle then the value of its 'bounds' key is a list containing four integers x0,y0,x1,y1. These are the coordinates of diagonally opposite corners of a rectangle. The triangle is the half of the rectangle that is formed by dividing the rectangle along a diagonal so that (x0,y0) is the right-angle of the triangle, and (x1,y1) is outside the triangle as illustrated below.", I'm sorry, I'm trying to do this, I don't really understand why I need to add data? the stuff in quotes is from my coursework and is why I am confused :(

Comment: @Isuckatcoding111: you didn't mention that the coordinates represent opposite corners of a rectangle. In that case you just need to do a little math based on the instructions in order to come up with the third coordinate to pass to `create_polygon`.

Comment: @lsuckatcoding111 If they are coordinates of the diagonal bisector of a rectangle, then how do you determine which part, the upper or the lower, after the bisection is the final right-angle triangle?

Answer (score 0):

You are given the bounding box of various polygons; drawing polygons on `tkinter.Canvas` requires a sequence of vertices. One approach is to use the bounding box values to benerate the vertices values. This can be done upon parsing your file.

for instance (using a string to replace your file):

```
import tkinter as tk


def drawOnCanvas(canvas, shape):
    """takes a shape, a bbox, and a fill, and draws a polygon on canvas"""
    sh, bbox, fill = shape
    vertices = make_vertices_from_bbox(sh, bbox)
    
    color = 'white'
    if fill:
        color = 'black'
    canvas.create_polygon(*vertices, fill=color)
    
def make_rect_vertices(bbox):
    """returns the vertices for a rectangle"""
    x0, y0, x2, y2 = bbox
    x1, y1 = x0, y2
    x3, y3 = x2, y0
    return (x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    
def make_tri_vertices(bbox):
    """returns the vertices for a triangle
    
    Note that there are many alternate ways to choose the vertices
    """
    x0, y0, x2, y2 = bbox
    x1, y1 = x0, y2
    return (x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2)

def make_vertices_from_bbox(shape, bbox):
    """calls the proper helper and returns the vertices"""
    if shape == 'rect':
        return make_rect_vertices(bbox)
    if shape == 'tri':
        return make_tri_vertices(bbox)
    raise ValueError(f'the shape {shape} is not defined')
        
def parse_f(f):
    shapes = []
    for line in f.split('\n'):
        poly, x0, y0, x1, y1, fill = line.split()
        shapes.append((poly, (int(x0), int(y0), int(x1), int(y1)), eval(fill)))
    return shapes
        
f = """rect 20 20 80 50 True
tri 80 50 20 35 False
rect 80 20 115 62 True
tri 122 27 143 20 True
tri 122 27 143 34 True
tri 122 41 143 34 True
tri 122 41 143 48 True
tri 122 55 143 48 True
tri 122 55 143 62 True"""

parse_f(f)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white', height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()


for shape in parse_f(f):
    drawOnCanvas(canvas, shape)


root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, it does, thank you @BryanOakley - I removed the redundant vertex.